Monolith vs microservices with NestJs
I'm currenly woking on a project where I need to save some media file (like video) using a NestJS project.
I'm already created the monorepo strucutre where I'm using RabbitMQ for broadcasting messaged and a bunch of servicies:

API gateway (the one that received the HTTP requests and convert them to rabbit messages

a Database service (that knows where the files are (something like : filename = ""; pahtTOFIle = "")

a Storage service (that realli saves and retrieve the files)


Now I'm facing an issue: how can I transfer the files from the gateway to the storage service ?
Using Rabbit is a no option 'cause the file could be up to 10 GB ...
Any help will be appreciated.
I've already created the project
